# Eloquent where clause not working with int value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have thousands of Eloquent queries on my Laravel application that worked well on v5.2, but after I upgraded the application to the latest version they stopped working as expected.

For example, I have an eloquent query with the following where clause with an integer parameter:

```
->where('categories.is_list', 1)
```

It just doesn't work unless I change the int parameter to a string `1 => '1'`.

Is there a parameter to change this behavior globally? As I don't want to update all my queries one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of `is_list`? Its name suggests it should be a `tinyint()` (allows `0` and `1`, aka a boolean `true` / `false`), but that code suggests it's a `varchar()` (or similar). Are you able to migrate the column to a correct numeric datatype?

Comment: I don't really know as I don't have access to the database. The project was already created and I'm updating it. It was working good before the upgrade, so I don't know if it have something to do with PHP. Perhaps it had a special PHP configuration that got overwritten with the PHP upgrade.

Comment: Hmm, fair points. I'm not familiar with any issues that would arise from something like this, but I also haven't worked with Laravel 5 in quite some time. Might have to do some DB debugging, like tacking on `->toSql()` to see the query, running that against your local DB (I would hope you have a local DB and aren't trying to upgrade directly against live/production data, but that's a separate point). Hopefully someone can help you, but it might also be super specific to your setup. Best of luck!

Comment: Sadly I don't have a local DB. I'm upgrading on a staging server because the clients are too restrictive on this matter. I was hoping that PHP had some configuration to treat integers as string, but if not then I guess I'll have to update the queries one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql array in the config/database php change:

```
'strict' => false
```

To

```
'strict' => true
```

Comment: Yes, that was already set to false.

Comment: Apologize. I edited my answer. False to true.

Comment: Yes, I tried both without luck. It worked on the prior versions, but after the upgrade it came with this weird behavior. I guess it has something to do with PHP, as I had to upgrade PHP and I don't know if there was a default value for this on the other PHP version, which was 5.4.